# Max-width of image without knowing image size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, width

I was wondering if there is a way with CSS to set the `max-width` of images in a site without know what the width of the images are?

Right now, I currently have this set in my CSS:

`img {width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;}`

which will set all of the images to fill the full width of the browser and flex when the browser resizes.

The only thing that I'm wondering about is if a user uploads an image into the CMS (Wordpress in this case), how can I get the the width of that image so that it's possible to set the `max-width` of the image so that it doesn't stretch all the way out and without having to set a generic value in the CSS? Is there any way with CSS, or do I have to go the javascript route?

My reason for asking is that I'm not sure about the dimensions of some images that the user might add/update on their site.

In the past I've always declared the `max-width` value in a specific class (example):

`.post img {max-width: 300px;}`

Which was fine since I knew the width of the images before hand. But like I mentioned before, I'm not sure what the width of some of the images will be when they upload and add them onto the site.

Answer (score 0):

obviously you need the max-width value when you preview each image.

how about if you put this image in a table which is placed where
you want and has the `max-width` you want (according to your screen width)
and set the `image width` be the 100% of the `table width`.e.g.

```
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="your.img.url" style="width:100%"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

of course the image will be stretched each time you resize your browser
or even if the original image width is less than your table width

Comment: Yeah, I figured that I HAVE to get the max-width value in order for it retain the image's proper width.

I'll see if I can tinker around with something in JS. Or maybe check to see if I can use it with inserting the inline style.